# Android - Intercept Google Analytics Campaign issue

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've finished the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=en) and able to [debug and send broadcasts manually](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#broadcast)

But I can't intercept the referrer data with another custom receiver. It simply doesn't trigger on incoming broadcast `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`.

If I send broadcast to `/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver` custom receiver not see it. Otherways, sending to exactly `co.primesignals.android.primesignalsapp.campaign.LaunchReceiver` works fine. But google sends that broadcast to own receiver...

**How to implement custom receiver properly to intercept campaign referrer?**

Manifest:

```
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

     <!--Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver                            
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".campaign.LaunchReceiver" //custom receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

LaunchReceiver:

```
public class LaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String INSTALL_REFERRER_ACTION = "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER";
public static final String REFERRER = "referrer";
public static final String TAG = "GAv4 app ->";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "LaunchReceiver.onReceive");

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action) && INSTALL_REFERRER_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, String.format("LaunchReceiver.onReceive action=%s", action));
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra(REFERRER);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(referrer)) {
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, String.format("LaunchReceiver.onReceive referrer=%s", referrer));

            SPManager.add(context, REFERRER, referrer);

            CampaignData.parseAndSaveData(context, referrer);
        }
    }

    new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);
}
}
```

ADB shell commands I used to pass broadcasts:

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "[package]/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "[referrer value]" -> this is not handled by custom receiver

am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "[package]/co.primesignals.android.primesignalsapp.campaign.LaunchReceiver" --es referrer "[referrer value]" -> this works perfect but google wont send this broadcast
```

Answer (score 1):

Make exported="true" for AnalyticsReceiver and CampaignTrakingReceiver. For more refer https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns